# i want to find the frequency of all elemnts in a java array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to java and i'm wondering how to find the frequency of each element of a java array?
this is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int vl=0;
    int a[]={1,2,3,4};

    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++){
        if(a[i]==a[j]){
            vl++; 
            System.out.println(vl);


        }else System.out.println(vl);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the result output you expect ?

Answer (score 3):

One of the possible ways to do this - is to use a `HashMap` where a map key is your element and a value is element frequency:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,2,3};
HashMap<Integer, Integer> frequency = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    if (frequency.containsKey(a[i])) {
        frequency.put(a[i], frequency.get(a[i]) + 1 );
    } else {
        frequency.put(a[i], 1);
    }
}
System.out.println(frequency);
```

or more Java-8 approach:

```
Map<Integer,Long> f = Arrays.stream(a).boxed().
      collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
System.out.println(f);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a hash map based implementation where in the key in the hash map is the array element and the value is the frequency of the element.

Once you iterate over the entire array, you can get the key set of the hash map and print the frequencies of all elements. This approach will be more efficient in terms of time complexity.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Count_Occurrence
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int n, x, count = 0, i = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter no. of elements you want in array:");
        n = s.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter all the elements:");
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a[i] = s.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.print("Enter the element of which you want to count number of occurrences:");
        x = s.nextInt();
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if(a[i] == x)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of Occurrence of the Element:"+count);
    }
}
```

This program can give the frequency of one element in the array at a time.

If you can do one .
You can iterate with all occurrences.

Comment: It is counterproductive to feed OP an answer, especially without any explanation of where his code is wrong.

Comment: was this approach wrong ...

Comment: Never mind your approach, it is a right approach to doing something entirely different (counting frequency of one specific item). His approach is wrong for what he wants to achieve, and that is what needs to be explained to him.

Comment: Thanks for the guideline...